# Hide a column in one repeater based on the value of a checkbox in another

Tags: c#, checkbox, sitecore, repeater

I have a product listing page which has several divs set up to look like a table. The product listing is inside one of two repeaters. The outer most repeater (called locationRepeater) sets the location area name for each batch of products (Public Areas, Showers and Sinks), and the second repeater (areaRepeater) generates the listing of products (I can't go back and redo the code so I only use 1 repeater--there's no time for that):

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="locationRepeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="SetInner">   
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="LocationName">
             <%# Eval("SecOpen") %><%# Eval("LocationName")%> <%# Eval("SecClose") %>
        </div>
        <asp:Repeater ID="areaRepeater" runat="server">  
         <HeaderTemplate>
            <div class="headerRow">
                    <div class="header">
                        <div class="thumb"><p></p></div>
                        <div class="headerField name"><p class="hField">Product</p></div>
                        <div class="headerField sku"><p class="hField">GOJO SKU</p></div>
                        <div class="headerField size"><p class="hField">Size</p></div>
                        <div class="headerField case"><p class="hField">Case Pack</p></div>
                        <div class="headerField qty"><p class="hField">Add to Shopping List</p></div>
                    </div>
             </div>
        </HeaderTemplate>      
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:placeholder id="LocationAreaHeader" runat="server" visible='<%# (Eval("AreaName").ToString().Length == 0  ? false : true) %>' ><h3> <%# Eval("AreaName") %></h3></asp:placeholder>

                    <asp:placeholder id="ProductTable" runat="server" visible='<%# (Eval("ProductName").ToString().Length == 0  ? false : true) %>' >

                       <div class="table">
                           <div class="row">
                               <div class="thumb"><%# Eval("Charm") %></div>
                                <div class="field name"><p class="pField"> <%# Eval("ThumbOpen") %><%# Eval("ProductName") %><%# Eval("ThumbClose") %></p> </div>
                                <div class="field sku"><p class="pField"> <%# Eval("Sku") %> </p></div>
                                <div class="field size"><p class="pField"> <%# Eval("Size") %></p></div>
                                <div class="field case"><p class="pField"> <%# Eval("CasePack") %> </p></div>
                                <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="ShoppingField">
                                    <div class="field qty"><p class="pField"> <asp:checkbox id="LineQuantity" runat="server" /></p></div>
                                </asp:PlaceHolder>  
                            </div>
                        </div>
                           <asp:Label id="productID" text='<%# Eval("productID") %>' visible="false" runat="server" />
                    </asp:placeholder>
               <!-- Stored values -->

               <asp:Label id="SkuID" runat="server" text='<%# Eval("SkuID") %>' visible="true" />
               <asp:Label id="masterSku" runat="server" text='<%# Eval("masterSku") %>' visible="false" />
               <asp:Label id="masterName" runat="server" text='<%# Eval("masterName" ) %>' visible="false" />

             <asp:Label ID="test" visible="false" runat="server" text='<%# Eval("AreaID") %>' />

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>

        <asp:Label ID="refID" visible="false" runat="server" text='<%# Eval("LocationID") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

In the template for the product listing page is a checkbox called "Shopping Disabled" which is meant to hide a column from the areaRepeater's product listing table if it's checked. However, the "Shopping Disabled" checkbox exists inside the first repeater (locationRepeater). How can I hide the "Add to Shopping" column based on a value found inside the creation of the locationRepeater?

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                Item CurrentItem = Sitecore.Context.Item;

                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                DataTable locations = ds.Tables.Add("locations");

                locations.Columns.Add("LocationName", Type.GetType("System.String"));
                locations.Columns.Add("LocationID", Type.GetType("System.String"));
                locations.Columns.Add("SecOpen", Type.GetType("System.String"));
                locations.Columns.Add("SecClose", Type.GetType("System.String"));
                string secColor = "";
                if (CurrentItem.TemplateName == "gojoProductLocation")
                {
                    Sitecore.Data.Fields.CheckboxField checkbox = CurrentItem.Fields["Active"];
                    if (checkbox.Checked)
                    {   
                        DataRow dr = locations.NewRow();
                        dr["LocationName"] = CurrentItem.Fields["Header"].Value;
                        dr["LocationID"] = CurrentItem.ID.ToString();

                        locations.Rows.Add(dr);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Item HomeItem = ScHelper.FindAncestor(CurrentItem, "gojoMarket");

                    if (HomeItem != null)
                    {
                        Item ProductGroup = HomeItem.Axes.SelectSingleItem(@"child::*[@@templatename='gojoMarketOfficeBuildigProductMap']/*[@@templatename='gojoProductList']");

                        if (ProductGroup != null)
                        {
                           //this is where I can get the value of the "Shopping Disabled" checkbox
                            Sitecore.Data.Fields.CheckboxField checkBox = ProductGroup.Fields["Shopping Disabled"];
                            if (checkBox.Checked)
                            {
                                submitBtn.Visible = false;

                            }

                            Item[] LocationList = ProductGroup.Axes.SelectItems(@"child::*[@@templatename='gojoProductLocation' and @Active = '1']");

                            if (LocationList != null)
                            {

                                foreach (Item LocationItem in LocationList)
                                {
                                    DataRow dr = locations.NewRow();
                                    secColor = LocationItem.Fields["Section Color"].Value;
                                    dr["SecOpen"] = "<h1 style='padding-top: 10px; background-color:#" + secColor + "'>";
                                    dr["LocationName"] = LocationItem.Fields["Header"].Value;
                                    dr["LocationID"] = LocationItem.ID.ToString();
                                    dr["SecClose"] = "</h1>";
                                    locations.Rows.Add(dr);

                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                locationRepeater.DataSource = ds;
                locationRepeater.DataMember = "locations";
                locationRepeater.DataBind();
                if (locationRepeater.Items.Count == 0)
                {
                    //show message -RTE field on product map page
                    Literal lit = (Literal)FindControl("Return");
                }

            }
        }
        //This function populates the second repeater, which has the "Add to Shopping" column I want to hide
        protected void SetInner(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.Footer) & (e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.Header))
            {             
                Label refID = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("refID");
                Label test = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("test");
                Repeater areaRepeater = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("areaRepeater");

                Database db = Sitecore.Context.Database;
                Item LocationAreaItem = db.Items[refID.Text];

                if (LocationAreaItem != null)
                {
                    Item[] AreaList = LocationAreaItem.Axes.SelectItems(@"child::*[@@templatename='gojoProductLocationArea' and @Active = '1']");

                    if (AreaList != null)
                    {
                        DataSet dset = new DataSet();
                        DataTable areas = dset.Tables.Add("areas");

                        string secColor = "";
                        areas.Columns.Add("AreaName", Type.GetType("System.String"));
                        areas.Columns.Add("Sku", Type.GetType("System.String"));
                        areas.Columns.Add("Large Image", Type.GetType("System.String"));
                        areas.Columns.Add("Charm", Type.GetType("System.String"));
                        areas.Columns.Add("ProductName", Type.GetType("System.String"));
                        areas.Columns.Add("masterSku", Type.GetType("System.String"));
                        areas.Columns.Add("masterName", Type.GetType("System.String"));
                        areas.Columns.Add("Size", Type.GetType("System.String"));
                        areas.Columns.Add("CasePack", Type.GetType("System.String"));
                        areas.Columns.Add("SkuID", Type.GetType("System.String"));
                        areas.Columns.Add("AreaID", Type.GetType("System.String"));
                        areas.Columns.Add("productID", Type.GetType("System.String"));
                        areas.Columns.Add("ThumbOpen", Type.GetType("System.String"));
                        areas.Columns.Add("ThumbClose", Type.GetType("System.String"));

                        foreach (Item AreaItem in AreaList)
                        {
                            DataRow drow = areas.NewRow();

                            drow["AreaName"] = AreaItem.Fields["Header"].Value;
                            drow["AreaID"] = AreaItem.ID.ToString();

                            areas.Rows.Add(drow);

                            Item[] SkuList = AreaItem.Axes.SelectItems(@"child::*[(@@templatename='gojoPTRefill' or @@templatename = 'gojoPTAccessories' or  @@templatename = 'gojoPTDispenser' or @@templatename = 'gojoPTSelfDispensed') and @Active = '1']");

                            foreach (Item ChildItem in SkuList)
                            {
                                Item MarketProduct = db.Items[ChildItem.Fields["Reference SKU"].Value];

                                drow["productID"] = ChildItem.ID.ToString();

                                if (MarketProduct != null)
                                {
                                    Item MasterProduct = db.Items[MarketProduct.Fields["Master Product"].Value];
                                    if (MasterProduct != null)
                                    {
                                        DataRow newRow = areas.NewRow();

                                        if (MasterProduct.TemplateName == "gojoSKUSelfDispensed" || MasterProduct.TemplateName == "gojoSKURefill")
                                        {
                                            newRow["Size"] = MasterProduct.Fields["Size"].Value;
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            newRow["Size"] = "N/A";
                                        }
                                        Sitecore.Data.Fields.XmlField fileField = ChildItem.Fields["Charm"];
                                        newRow["Charm"] = "<image src=\"" + ScHelper.GetCorrectFilePath(fileField) + "\" border=\"0\" alt=\"\">";
                                        newRow["Sku"] = MasterProduct.Fields["SKU"].Value;
                                        newRow["productID"] = ChildItem.ID.ToString();
                                        newRow["CasePack"] = MasterProduct.Fields["Case Pack"].Value;
                                        newRow["Large Image"] = "";

                                        try
                                        {
                                            string prodNameLink = "";
                                            Item MasterProductName = db.Items[MasterProduct.Fields["Complete Product Name"].Value];
                                            string prodImg = MasterProduct.Fields["Large Image"].Value;
                                            if (prodImg != "")
                                            {
                                                Sitecore.Data.Fields.XmlField productImg = MasterProduct.Fields["Large Image"];
                                                prodNameLink = MasterProduct.Fields["Large Image"].Value;
                                                newRow["ThumbOpen"] = string.Format("<a href=\"{0}\" class=\"fancybox\" title=\"{1}\" rel=\"image\">", ScHelper.GetCorrectFilePath(productImg), MasterProduct.Fields["SKU"].Value);
                                                newRow["ThumbClose"] = "</a>";
                                            }

                                        if (MasterProductName != null)
                                        {
                                            newRow["ProductName"] = MasterProductName.Fields["Complete Name"].Value;
                                        }


                                        areas.Rows.Add(newRow);
                                        }
                                        catch (Exception x)
                                        {
                                            Response.Write(x.Message.ToString() + "<br />");
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        areaRepeater.DataSource = dset;
                        areaRepeater.DataMember = "areas";
                        areaRepeater.DataBind();
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding correctly, you are looking to hide a column which is represented as a div?

If this is the case add the attribute `runat="server"` to your div that you wish to hide.

In the code behind you will then be able to use findcontrol to find the checkbox, *areaRepeater*, and the div and then you will be able to set the visibility of the div based on your checkbox.

It would be something like:

```
foreach(Repeater rep in locationRepeater.Items)
{ 
    Repeater areaRepeater = (Repeater)rep.FindControl("areaRepeater");
    CheckBox disable = (CheckBox)rep.FindControl("checkboxid");
    foreach(Repeater areaRep in areaRepeater.Items)
    {
        HtmlGenericControl div = (HtmlGenericControl)areaRep.FindControl("div");
        div.Visible = disable.Checked;
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems like a good idea, but the div I want to access is in the areaRepeater, not the locationRepeater...The former is inside the latter.

Comment: @SaraDeJaneiro - alright if you take a look at my updated answer, I believe I have corrected it to your situation. Looking for the area repeater inside the location repeater. I believe this is what you are trying to figure out. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

There are likely better ways to handle this but since you are already using the approach of storing data in hidden fields (ex: "refID") you can take this same approach for the "Shopping Disabled" field.

Add a new Column to your DataTable in your Page_Load:

```
    locations.Columns.Add("ShoppingDisabled", Type.GetType("System.String"));
```

Add the shopping disabled data to this Column in your Page_Load:

```
     dr["ShoppingDisabled"] = checkBox.Checked;
     locations.Rows.Add(dr);
```

Add the hidden label to your User Control:

```
     <asp:Label ID="ShoppingDisabled" visible="false" runat="server" text='<%# Eval("ShoppingDisabled") %>' />
```

Grab the label in your SetInner() method:

```
    Label lblShoppingDisabled = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("ShoppingDisabled");
```

Add logic to your SetInner() method or the user control to hide what you ever you need to hide based on lblShoppingDisalbed.Text.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so, what I ended up doing was creating a function that got the value of the "Shopping Disabled" checkbox and set a boolean variable to either true or false based on that. I then called this function inside the "visible" property of both the "Add To Shopping List" header and the checkbox field in the product listing table. This allowed me to show/hide that column as needed. Thanks for the suggestions, though!